# Handle timeout with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

Is it possible to add timeout handler for Alamofire request?

In my project I use Alamofire this way:

```
init() {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30

    self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
}

func requestAuthorizationWithEmail(email:NSString, password:NSString, completion: (result: RequestResult) -> Void) {

    self.alamofireManager!.request(.POST, "myURL", parameters:["email": email, "password":password])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                //do json stuff
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                completion(result: .ConnectionFailed)
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

request fail message

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc10b937320 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=url, NSErrorFailingURLKey=url, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

Comment: The response object will contain the HTTP status. If it is 408 (408 Request Timeout), then you can check that inside the `.Failure` call and handle it appropriately. There are probably even macros for the http-statuses so you can simply check something like `HTTP_STATUS_408` as an integer placeholder.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can compare `error._code` and if it is equal to `-1001` which is [`NSURLErrorTimedOut`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrortimedout?language=objc) then you know this was a timeout.

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

manager.request("yourUrl", method: .post, parameters: ["parameterKey": "value"])
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .success: // succes path 
            case .failure(let error):
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    print("Request timeout!")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I use this snippet to handle timeout error. My platform is Xcode 8, Swift 3. the enum result value seems to be `.success` and `.failure` instead of `.Success` and `.Failure`.

Comment: can anyone tell me how does one know to use `error._code`? This does not seem to appear in any documentation

Answer (score 21):

Swift 3

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

After a lot of research, I did it like this:

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

manager.request("yourUrl", method: .post, parameters: ["parameterKey": "value"])
```

Answer (score 13):

### Swift 3, Alamofire 4.5.0

I wanted to set the same *timeout* for every HTTP call in my project.

The key idea is to declare the *Alamofire Session Manager* **as a global variable**. Then to create a *URLSessionConfiguration* variable, set its timeout in seconds and assign it to the manager.

Every call in the project can use this configured *session manager*.

In my case the global *Alamofire Session Manager* variable was set in *AppDelegate* file (globally) and its configuration was managed in its *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

var AFManager = SessionManager()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4 //seconds
        AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

From now the *Alamofire request* function can be called from any part of the app using the *afManager*.

For example:

```
AFManager.request("yourURL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON { response in
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5, Alamofire 5**

The cleanest way I found, that works with the latest version of Alamofire is the following:

```
AF.request(url).response { (dataResponse: AFDataResponse<Data?>) in
    switch dataResponse.result {
    case .success(let data):
        // succes path
    case .failure(let error):
        switch error {
        case .sessionTaskFailed(URLError.timedOut):
            print("Request timeout!")
        default:
            print("Other error!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.x**

```
class NetworkHelper {
    static let shared = NetworkHelper()
    var manager: SessionManager {
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        return manager
    }
    func postJSONData( withParams parameters: Dictionary<String, Any>, toUrl urlString: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error,_ responseBody: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?)->()) {
        manager.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in 
            if let error = response.result.error {
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    print("Time out occurs!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.x**

Accepted answer didn't worked for me too.

This work for me!

```
let url = URL(string: "yourStringUrl")!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 5 // or what you want
```

And after:

```
Alamofire.request(urlRequest).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
    /// code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

This my way and timeout feature is workable, meanwhile practices singleton for api class.
reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803856/set-timeout-in-alamofire)

```
struct AlamofireManager {
    static let shared: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: SessionDelegate(), serverTrustPolicyManager: nil)
        return sessionManager
    }()
}

class Auth {
    static let api = Auth()

    private init() {}

    func headers() -> HTTPHeaders {
        return [
            "Accept": "XXX",
            "Authorization": "XXX",
            "Content-Type": "XXX"
        ]
    }

    func querySample() {

        AlamofireManager.shared.request("api_post_url", method: .post, parameters: ["parametersKey": "value"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers())
            .responseJSON(queue: DispatchQueue.global(), options: []) { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                // do your statement
            case .failure(let error):
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    // timeout error statement
                } else {
                    // other error statement
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func queryOtherSample() {

        AlamofireManager.shared.request("api_get_url", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers())
            .responseJSON(queue: DispatchQueue.global(), options: []) { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                // do your statement
            case .failure(let error):
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    // timeout error statement
                } else {
                    // other error statement
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me why specifying the background thread there solves this problem !

Comment: I think this error due to multiple request to query on serial queue at same time.
improved the DispatchQueue.global() to concurrent queue.

Comment: I did the same like you said but I keep getting canceled, in the end I just created a `URLRequest` and passed it to `Alamofire.request` and solved the problem

Comment: @brahimm I saw your issue, meanwhile find solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803856/set-timeout-in-alamofire/44298030#44298030).

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 3.x** / **Swift 4.0** / **Swift 5.0** users with **Alamofire >= 5.0**

Used request modifier to increase and decrease the timeout interval.

**Alamofire's** request creation methods offer the most common parameters for customization but sometimes those just aren't enough. The URLRequests created from the passed values can be modified by using a RequestModifier closure when creating requests. For example, to set the **URLRequest's** **timeoutInterval** to 120 seconds, modify the request in the closure.

```
var manager = Session.default
 manager.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: dict, headers: headers, requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = 120 }).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

**OR**

RequestModifiers also work with trailing closure syntax.

```
var manager = Session.default
     manager.request("https://httpbin.org/get") { urlRequest in
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 60
    urlRequest.allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess = false
}
.response(...)
```

You can also check it [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1931#issuecomment-726824066)

Answer (score 0):

Make extension of SessionManager and write a public static variable like this,
"requestTimeOutInterval" this is a public variable. it has time.

```
extension SessionManager {
    public static let custom: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = requestTimeOutInterval
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.0, Alamofire 5.4.2

The error code when time out always equal to **NSURLErrorTimedOut**, so
I try to retrieve Error object from AFError and upcast to NSError.

```swift
extension AFError {
    var isTimeout: Bool {
        if isSessionTaskError,
           let error = underlyingError as NSError?,
           error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut //-1001
        {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Invoke on response closure.

```swift
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/delay/10")!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2)
AF.request(request).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(_):
        print("success")
    case .failure(let error):
        if error.isTimeout {
            print("Timeout!")
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Alamofire 5.5 SessionManager has been renamed Session**

Here is the documentation link
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#breaking-api-changes

Also the example of user

```
let manager = Alamofire.Session.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
        let headers: HTTPHeaders? = token == nil ? nil : [.authorization(bearerToken: token!),.accept("application/json")]
        manager.request(path, method: method, parameters: parameter, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:

            case .failure:

            }
        }
```