# Set timeout in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 4.0.1 and **I want to set a timeout for my request**. I tried the solutions gived in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626075/handle-timeout-with-alamofire):

**In the first case**, it throws a ***NSURLErrorDomain*** (timeout is set correctly):

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10

    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    sessionManager.request("yourUrl", method: .post, parameters: ["parameterKey": "value"])
            .responseJSON {
                response in
                switch (response.result) {
                case .success:
                    //do json stuff
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                        //timeout here
                    }
                    print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                    break
                }
            }
```

**In the second case**, the time out is not replaced and still set as 60 seconds.

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10

manager.request("yourUrl", method: .post, parameters: ["parameterKey": "value"])
```

**I am running in ios 10.1**

**My code:** (it doesn't work)

```
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
    let alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

    alamoFireManager.request("my_url", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in


        switch (response.result) {
        case .success:
                 //Success....
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            // failure...
            break
        }
    }
```

**Solved Alamofire github thread:** [Alamofire 4.3.0 setting timeout throws NSURLErrorDomain error #1931](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1931#issuecomment-274826417)

Comment: you are setting Request Time Out , set Resource Timeout instead. 
`timeoutIntervalForResource`

Comment: it seems doesn't work, I updated with my actual code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based in @kamal-thakur response.

**Swift 3**:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL.init(string: "YOUR_URL") as! URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.timeoutInterval = 10 // 10 secs
let postString = "param1=\(var1)&param2=\(var2)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
    response in
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 40):

Alamofire 5.1 includes a new way to modify the request with a closure in the initializer:

```swift
AF.request(url) { $0.timeoutInterval = 60 }
    .validate()
    .response { _ in // handle response here }
```

Comment: To be honest, Alamofire gives too much flexibility on declaring certain things which leads to confusion. Those kind of settings better be restricted to Session. Imagine each developers starts setting their own time out interval on their newly developed API. This can be prevented by creating one more layer of Proxy (or wrapper) around Alamofire to execute requests but still add verbosity for no reason.

Answer (score 36):

For new versions of AF, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61192412/308315

---

For old versions, please try this:

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.timeoutInterval = 10 // 10 secs
    let values = ["key": "value"]
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: [])
    Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON {
        response in
        // do whatever you want here
    }
```

Comment: hmm i seem to get this error: Could not cast value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' to 'Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible'.

Comment: try 'var request = URLRequest(url: url)' instead of 'let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)'

Comment: Works like a champ!!

Answer (score 28):

I have same problem too, I think I found the solution. Try to declare `SessionManager?`or in your case `alamofireManager` in class, outside the function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var alamoFireManager : SessionManager? // this line

   func alamofire(){
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
        alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration) // not in this line

        alamoFireManager.request("my_url", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in


        switch (response.result) {
        case .success:
                 //Success....
            break
        case .failure(let error):
               // failure...
             break
       }
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Try to declare SessionManager?or in your case alamofireManager in class, outside the function <- this is the main point!!

Comment: You save my day bro. The best answer (Y).

Answer (score 15):

If you are using one instance of Alamofire, you can make a lazy var like this:

```
   private lazy var alamoFireManager: SessionManager? = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
    let alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    return alamoFireManager

}()
```

Works on **Swift 4.2**

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 4 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 4
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Same result than the first case.

Comment: @ƒernandoValle Instead of editing other peoples answers you should incorporate the changes into your question or create an own asnwer.

Comment: @LotPings I updated my question and I updated this code because is easy for check if there is any error.

Answer (score 10):

As Matt said the problem is the following

> The difference here is that the initialized manager is not owned, and is deallocated shortly after it goes out of scope. As a result, any pending tasks are cancelled.

The solution to this problem was written by rainypixels

import Foundation
import Alamofire

```
class NetworkManager {

    var manager: Manager?

    init() {
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

And my own version

```
class APIManager {

    private var sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager()

    func requestCards(_ days_range: Int, success: ((_ cards: [CardModel]) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let parameters = ["example" : 1]

            let headers = ["AUTH" : "Example"]

            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
            self.sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

            self.sessionManager.request(URLs.cards.value, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    //do json stuff
                    guard let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
                    guard let result = json["result"] as? [[String : Any]] else { return }
                    let cards = Mapper<CardModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: result)
                    debugPrint("cards", cards.count)
                    success?(cards)
                case .failure(let error):
                    if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                        //timeout here
                        debugPrint("timeOut")
                    }
                    debugPrint("\n\ncard request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                    fail?(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can also make a manager for it

```
import Alamofire

struct AlamofireAppManager {

    static let shared: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        return sessionManager
    }()

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on Letaief Achraf's answer, but for **`Swift 5.0`** and **`Alamofire pod version >= 5.0.0`**

```
//MARK: - Session Manager
private static var alamofireManager: Session? = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
    let alamofireManager = Session(configuration: configuration)
    return alamofireManager
}()
```

Use this variable inside an `APIManager` or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5. You can do in this way.

```
AF.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the latest release 5.4.4, you can set the time out like this:

```
AF.request("https://stackoverflow.com", requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = 5 }).response(...)
```

[Here's the documentation.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md)

Example:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")

AF.request(url, method: .get, requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = .infinity }).validate().responseData { response in
    // Do something with the response ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after a lot of try I made it whit the next:

```
var timeout = 300 // 5 minutes

//Post values
    let parameters:Parameters = parameters

    //Server value
    let url:URL = (url)


    //Make the request
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(timeout)
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(timeout)

    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

     sessionManager.request(url,parameters:parameters).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { response in


        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // URL response

        print(sessionManager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest)   // result of response time
        print(response.timeline.totalDuration)


        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            if let valJSON = response.result.value {


               //use your json result 



            }

        case .failure (let error):

            print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")

        }
    }
```

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: What's the difference between your response and Jason's? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41804031/469218

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me:

```
let url:String = "http://..."
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("Kirk Hamet", forHTTPHeaderField:"name")
request.timeoutInterval = 23 //Second

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
                response in
    if response.result.isSuccess == true {

    }else{

    }

}
```

**Swift 4.1**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to build a UrlRequest yourself, you can still use Alamofire to build it.

```
    // set this flag to false so the request will not be sent until
    // resume() is called
    sessionManager.startRequestsImmediately = false

    var urlRequest = sessionManager.request(url,
                                            method: method,
                                            parameters: params,
                                            encoding: encoding,
                                            headers: allHeaders).request!

    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 10

    let request = sessionManager.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { (result) in
        // use the result
    }

    // need to start the request
    request.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

**None of the above worked for me: Im on `swift 4.2` `Alamofire 4.5`**

I managed to solve it like this :

```swift
let request = Alamofire.request("routee", method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: getHeaders())

/// getting request created by Alamofire and then updating its timeout Value

let url = URL(string: "myroute")!
        var request = try URLRequest(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
        request.timeoutInterval = 900 // timeout
        request = try JSONEncoding.default.encode(request, with: data)

Alamofire.request(request)
    .responseJSON { response in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have code for swift 2.3 hope it helps you, try it

```
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10800 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10800 // seconds

    alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Same result than the first case.

Comment: take **var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.Manager!** as globally

Answer (score 0):

```
//MARK:- Working sessionManger
private static var sessionManger: Session? = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(timeOut)
    configuration.httpShouldUsePipelining = true
    let sessionManager = Session(configuration: configuration, startRequestsImmediately: true)
    return sessionManager
}()
```

Comment: This one is working try this one