# How to set request timeout with alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift

i tried with this code but not work

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
manager.upload( ....
```

any other ways or what's wrong with my code

EDIT : For request upload image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set timeout in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803856/set-timeout-in-alamofire)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I hope it helps, it worked for me:

### Global variable

```
private static var alamofireManager: SessionManager?
```

---

### Within your perform method

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default     
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeout //Any timeout value you want
let alamofireManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
self.alamofireManager = alamofireManager
let request = self.alamofireManager?.request(/* Your request parameters*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
 let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.url.background")
 configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(requestTimeOutInterval)
 alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```