# Alamofire Request Timed Out in just One Minute

Tags: ios, timeout, alamofire, swift5

When I invoke an `HTTP POST Request` using `Alamofire` it timed out in just one minute of time. Actually, the response is getting in after 2 minutes of request. So how can I change the request time out interval in alamofire? Please help…

The form to send request using alamofire is added below...

```
Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: my custom header
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON { (response) in 
  switch response.result { 
    case .success(let value):
    //code
    case .failure(let error):
    //code
  }
}
```

Comment: show your sample request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set timeout in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803856/set-timeout-in-alamofire)