# how to set timeout in alamofire with DataRequest

Tags: swift, alamofire, settimeout

```
let api = request(url, method: .post, parameters:params, headers:nil)

api.responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

        //code 
}
```

I don't have time to do code refactoring.
So I want to set the timeout based on the code above, how can I do it?

Comment: `SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set timeout in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803856/set-timeout-in-alamofire)

Answer (score 0):

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 12
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 12

let alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Session.init(configuration: configuration)
alamoFireManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in

   switch (response.result) {
   case .success:
         break
   case .failure(let error):
         print(error)
         break
   }

}
```