# Alamofire timeout not working in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, timeout, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for network request and want to add timeout. But Alamofire's function is not working. Nothing happens when I write the following code

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1 // not working, 20 secs normally (1 just for try)

    manager.request(url, method: method, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            ...
```

When I try without Alamofire for network request, timeout working successfully. But there are other mistakes.

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
request.httpMethod = "post"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.timeoutInterval = 1 // 20 secs normally (1 just for try)
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params!)
...
```

**So, how can i add timeout for Alamofire in Swift 3?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44948686/7825024

This configuration code does not work when I add my function, *but **it works** when I add it to **AppDelegate!***

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

var AFManager = SessionManager()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5 //seconds
        AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

**Example:**

```
AFManager.request("yourURL", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the values of a `URLSessionConfiguration` after it has be added to a `URLSession`, so attempting to manipulate `Alamofire.SesssionManager.default.session.configuration` will always fail. To properly change the configuration values, follow the Alamofire documentation for instantiating your own `SessionManager`. For example:

```
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
defaultHeaders["DNT"] = "1 (Do Not Track Enabled)"

let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```