# Alamofire post method in iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

For getting push notification here i am sending postitem, token, like count and currentname using alamofire post method(pod version alamofire 4.5). I did not get any response when post method called and it does not show any errors. 
I tried keeping breaking points in alamofire function, it call alamofire.requestion then it goes out function.

Here is the code tried to send post method to backend:

```
  func postNotification(postItem: String, post: Post) {

    print("Get token from post:::",post.token)
    print(postItem)
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")




    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type" :"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

       let parameters : [String:Any] = ["count":post.likeCount!, "likedby":currentName, "postId=":postItem, "token": post.token!]
    Alamofire.request("http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(data)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }

}
```

Getting console error like this

```
 2018-07-10 14:21:07.980212+0530 HighAvenue[10584:4236493] Task <B5FC98AB-C3FE- 
4D4F-9A93-72D3FFE35DF7>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0e478f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

Comment: have you checked it with other tools like postman... what was it response

Comment: @santhosh {
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "error": ""
}

Comment: Ok then i think the problem is with encoding try once with removing the encoding from the parameters or by using urlencoding.default. So, that it takes the default value

Comment: @santhosh how to do that..

Comment: replace Alamofire.request("http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil) with Alamofire.request("http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/", method: .post, parameters: parameters)

Comment: @santhosh it does not work..finished with error - code: -1002
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c5048fd0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL})

Comment: @santhosh tried by giving http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/ too

Comment: test with adding http:// as well i think it should work

Comment: yeah tested http:// stille it does not work..

Comment: @santhosh   let myParams = "count=\(post.likeCount!)&likedby=\(currentName)&postId=\(postItem)&token=\(post.token!)"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type" :"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        
        let parameters : [String:Any] = ["count":post.likeCount!, "likedby":currentName, "postId=":postItem, "token": post.token!]
        Alamofire.request("http://highavenue.co:9000/likesnotification/", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in  ------------this correct or not??]

Comment: @santhosh https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dGYwSl8_jRz_cM6TUNXQTJWT3IMaQqDf/view?usp=sharing can you check out this link

Comment: I think in parameters  "postId=":postItem should be  "postId":postItem

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not setting request time in your network call, by default your request time is a small interval, so please increase request timeout time. something like this,

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.timeoutInterval = 120 // 120 secs
let values = ["key": "value"]
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: [])
Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON {
    response in
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Second mistake in your code is you are trying to access ***http url*** which are by default are not allowed so you have to by pass this security from your app, Please refer to this answer in order to remove this security layer from your app.
[The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi/47302680#47302680)

Comment: Thanks for answering. it gets crashed . Could not cast value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' (0x1036f8d10) to 'Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible' (0x105a851b8).
2018-07-10 14:52:43.253861+0530 HighAvenue[10598:4246892] Could not cast value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' (0x1036f8d10) to 'Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible' (0x105a851b8).

Comment: you are probably trying to access Almofire.request that is something different, please make a request object just like this and then pass it to Almofire's function

Comment: Sorry! i could not get you.

Comment: no, problem, just compare your code with the chunk I provided you. you are passing arguments with in one line and I am creating a request object and then passing it to function. All I am saying is clean up your code and make this object of request and set time interval of 120 seconds.

Comment: you can check this answer for time interval ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626075/handle-timeout-with-alamofire?rq=1