# Alamofire set timeout only for specific a request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I'm sending requests using Alamofire as below. I need to know how can I set the timeout only for a specific request like this

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { (response) in switch response.result {

////

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set timeout in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803856/set-timeout-in-alamofire)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626075/handle-timeout-with-alamofire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a sessionManager for that specific request

```
let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
    var sessionManager = SessionManager()
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30  //timeout can be changed from here
    sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    return sessionManager
}()
```

and use this `sessionManager` for the call.

```
sessionManager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params)...
```

Comment: The problem: It's will apply for all request.

Comment: @DuyPhan No. It will only apply the configuration to requests that use `sessionManager.request`. Other requests can still use `Alamofire.request`

Answer (score 1):

for timeout use `timeoutInterval` for a specific url or request.

```
if let url = NSURL.init(string: "YOUR_URL") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        if let myUrl = NSURL.init(string: "SPECIFIC_URL"),
            myUrl.isEqual(url) {
            request.timeoutInterval = 10 // 10 secs
        }

        let postString = "param1=\(var1)&param2=\(var2)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
            ///  handle response here
        }
    }
```

according to [git hub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-validation) validate() checks for the status codes are within the `200..<300` range, and that the `Content-Type` header of the response matches the `Accept` header of the request, if one is provided.